# Question on trigometric graph sketching

Tags: trigonometry

Say I have to sketch the graph of

√2 sin A + √7 cos A

By R-formula,

√2 sin A + √7 cos A = 3 sin (A + 61.9 degrees)

So basically I have to sketch, 3 sin (A + 61.9 degrees)

Question 1:
Do I sketch the graph with the negative 61.9 or do I start from 0 degrees ?

Question 2:
Why does sin(x-a) [for example] shifts the graph to the right 
while sin(x+a) shifts graph to left?

I know this is similar to the turning for of a Completing The Square, (x-h)^2 + k but I don't understand the logic behind. Because usually a positive value gives impression that is to the right side of the equation.

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

> Why does $\sin(x+a)$ shifts graph to left?

Denote $X= x+a$, then draw $y = \sin X$.

Now, if you want to find the value of $\sin (x+a)$ at $x = 0$, i.e. $\sin (0+a)$, you have to copy the value at $X = a$ from the graph you have drawn, which is on the right of $0$ (for positive $a$).

If you want to find the value of $\sin (10+a)$, you have to copy from the graph at $X = 10+a$, which is another value on the right of $10$ (for positive $a$).

Which means, $y = \sin (x+a)$ is the left-shifted graph of $y = \sin X$ (for positive $a$).

Answer (score 1):

$$a sin x +b cos x=\\ a(sin x +\frac{b}{a} cos x)=\overset{\frac{b}{a}=tan(\theta )}{\rightarrow}\\a ( sin x + tan (\theta) cos x) \\=a(sinx  +\frac{sin (\theta)}{cos (\theta)}cos x)\\=a \frac{sinx cos (\theta)+sin  (\theta)cos x}{cos (\theta)}\\= a \frac{sin(x+\theta)}{cos (\theta)}\\=$$ now turn $cos(\theta)$ 
$$cos ^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{1+tan^2(\theta)}=\frac{1}{1+(\frac{b}{a})^2} \rightarrow  cos (\theta)=\pm \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}} $$
so we have $$ a \frac{sin(x+\theta)}{cos (\theta)}\\= \pm \sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+\theta)\\=\frac{|a|}{a}\sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+\theta)\\ \space  \\ \sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+\theta) , \space or ,-\sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x+\theta)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(-x-\theta)\\ not \space \sqrt{a^2+b^2} sin(x-\theta)$$[image]